# Stuck on Apple logo during upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: upgrade

After accepting an upgrade reboot from the App Store for an upgrade to High Sierra, my MacBook Pro retina 13 is stuck on the Apple Logo after the installation of this upgrade.

What do I do now?

A reinstall of the OS from recovery leads to the same hang. :(
[image: Have a look]

Comment: Tried Internet Recovery?

Comment: Did a reinstall using internet. Is that what u mean?

Comment: Had you re-formatted to APFS? If so, then you will probably have to totally reformat to HFS+ & start over.

Comment: @Tetsujin not reformatted anything

Comment: You're really not being very forthcoming... anyway, nuke & pave, reformat, install clean OS, update to Sierra, recover from backup.

Comment: So if I get you right only, a clean install would sort things out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be an option in the App Store to upgrade to High Sierra, as it is still in beta. My guess is that you opted into the beta and there are still bugs to work out. You might want to reformat from a previous backup.

Comment: Never opted for any beta inclusion. Fpr some reason, it got trickled down to me. As it showed up in my app store updates